# GPU doesn't recognize HDMI input automatically

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, gpu

I have a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 (Gigabyte) on my pc which is connected to my monitor via a DVI cable. I also have my TV screen connected to the GPU via an HDMI connection.
When I'm turning on my PC (windows 10), the GPU does not automatically detect the HDMI input (my TV screen). It doesn't show up on the Display Settings and turning the TV on and off doesn't help either.

In order for the GPU to detect the TV input, I have to go to the Device Manager tab in windows and disable-enable the Nvidia driver. After that, the GPU will detect it (even if I turn off the TV and turn it on again - the computer will still recognize it). That works fine until I turn off the computer . Then, the same cycle begins.

I would like to find a solution which won't require for me to disable-enable the driver every time I want to connect my PC to my TV, and would love to hear some possible solution on that.

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a driver issue, but I don't have anything to back that up with.  Try updating your drivers.  If it's the latest, try 1 or 2 versions back to see if it helps.  You monitors should be discovered regardless of whether they are on or off.

Comment: @computercarguy sorry, forgot to mention in my question that I have tried to update my driver several times, to newer and newer versions but unfortunately that didn't help...